# Grails: Check if a domain model object was created in code or loaded from the database

Tags: grails, domain-model

In Grails (or maybe Hibernate) is it possible to check if a domain model object was created in code (ie: it's a new object that has not yet been saved to the database) or if it was created by being loaded from the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use method isAttached - http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/isAttached.html.

Newly created objects are not attached to current session until .save() is called, the objects that were loaded from database are attached to the session.

Comment: This might work but could also get some false-positives because a persisted object can become detached from the session

Comment: It's not in the HTTP session, it's in the Hibernate Session - it's 1st-level cache

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the only way. Hibernate and GORM don't modify the domain classes other than to set the id after the `save()` call. If the instance does get disconnected then you're stuck, so be sure to add that logic to the is-new-or-persistent check or check before disconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

In grails 1.3.9 `isAttached()` does not seem to work when used in a Domain class custom validator.

I'm using `Date dateCreated` grails magic in all my domain objects and that worked against `null` check in the validator:

```
    date(blank: false, nullable: false, validator: { val, obj, errors ->
            // Validation only for new objects
            if (obj.dateCreated == null && obj.date <= new Date()) {
                errors.rejectValue('date', 'date.before.now');
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the domain instance will be assigned an id when it is persisted. So if the id property is null, it hasn't been saved to the database yet. If it came from the database, the instance will have a non-null id.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm dealing with a legacy database, so the ID gets manually assigned as soon as the objects get's created in code.  So this approach is a no-go for me.

Comment: Could you move the assigning of an ID to a beforeInsert?